# What happens when you return a JavaScript statement from a function, e.g. return console.log( "Hello" )

Tags: javascript

I've searched, but I don't think anyone has asked this question: essentially, what is the difference between

```
function $( input ){
    return console.log( input );
}

$( "My message" );
```

and the more conventional

```
function $( input ){
   console.log( input );
}

$( "My message" );
```

? They both  have the same effect.

If you can return it, does this mean that `console.log( "Hello" )` is an object?

Comment: Try it and find out? `console.log` (in Chrome at least) returns `undefined`, so it's the same as `return undefined`. The act of returning something doesn't make an object, or imply anything about something being an object.

Comment: So then why does it work?

Comment: It works because the javascript engine doesn't care what a function returns. It's a weakly typed language, so any function can return anything, including `null` or `undefined` values. It will affect your code later on if you return one of those, but you can assign any variable any value.

Comment: @user3457004 Why **wouldn't** it work? What about this makes you think it shouldn't work?

Comment: I understand now, but what was confusing to me was that the function was called when it was returned. Now I understand that you don't return the function (as you would if you did `return console.log;`), you return what it returns. Because I didn't understand that, what `console.log` returned was moot. But I get it now, thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function $( input ) {
    return console.log( input );
}
```

stands for:

```
function $( input ) {
    var ret = console.log( input );
    return ret;
}
```

Moreover, the return value of `console.log( input )` is `undefined`, and you return an `undefined` to the calling object. Nothing happens, because you discard the return value of `$( "My message" );`. you can use the return value in fact, such as:

```
var ret = $( "My message" );
console.log(ret);
```

and it will print `undefined` in the console.

Answer (score 4):

It's no different from returning any other value.

You're returning the return value of `console.log`, which doesn't return anything.

> If you can return it, does this mean that console.log( "Hello" ) is an object?

No. `console.log("Hello")` is a function call. Function calls *may* return a value explicitly.

Functions that do not have an explicit return value implicitly return `undefined`, like `console.log()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Console.log("Hello"); Return `undefined`, just do the test on a javascript shell :

```
var s = $("hello");
console.log(s);
```

This will print first Hello, in the Console.log code, then undefined : the s value

You can return it because undefined is an accepted return value, as `Console.log` isn't a **statement** but a **function**.

Comment: What is `var s = ...` doing there? You're not logging that, you're logging the string `"s"`, which is completely unrelated to the variable you've just created.

Comment: @meagar Indeed, Small mistake, I corrected, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`var test = $( "Hello" );` will make `test` whatever your `$` function returns.

The `console.log` does not return anything, so `var test = console.log('hey');` will make the value of `test` to become `undefined`.